# How to group together some of my turtle breeds?

Tags: netlogo

```
breed [hauls haul]            
breed [adults adult]
breed [pups pup]
breed [sps sp]
```

I have four breeds and it would be very convenient to create a group from adults and pups and refer to them as seals. Is it possible in Netlogo?

Answer (score 2):

that's what `turtle-set` is for. something like

```
set seals (turtle-set adults pups)
```

Alternatively, if they don't really have characteristics that are different from each other, you can simply have one breed of turtle and then have an attribute like 'agegroup'

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer is correct- you can get an agentset of all seals via

```
set seals (turtle-set adults pups)
```

BUT be aware that `seals` will only contain the adults and pups that were present when this statement was executed. `Seals` is not like `adults` and `pups` because it is not automatically updated when new adults or pups are created. If you use this statement once, `seals` will contain the seals present when you executed it (minus any that die) but not any new adults or pups.

The solution is to repeat the turtle-set statement any time you create pups or adults, including any time a pup turns into an adult. Or (depending on your code) it may work to execute the statement once per tick to update the `seals` agentset.